# Is there an IDE or editor with remote pairing options that include indicators for other users?

Tags: ide, editor, remote-access, pairing, pair-programming

I'm looking for a cross platform (Linux and Mac) remote pairing option that will allow users to see where the other users are working across open files and where they are in a specific file.  I used gobby for this years ago but it's Linux specific.  Presence indicators would be great, sort of how Google Docs handles it.

I've tried various plugins for Sublime Text, Atom, and VSCode.  Most of them allowed you to see when another use was typing but you couldn't see where their cursor was if they weren't typing.  None of the plugins provided any indication for when a user changed files or tabs.

I'd be especially elated if there were also features to share a shell and maybe network access to ports used by the code but that's not a requirement.  I've tried Gitpod but it's just VSCode so it has the problems that stock VSCode has.  I've also tried VNC, Remote Desktop, and screen control tools with video conferencing services but the input lag was too high.

Currently we're simply connecting to a remote server via SSH and using tmux+vim to get things done but some folks prefer GUIs so I'm looking to scratch that itch.